# Clion, Autotools and JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, clion, autotools

I'm trying to setup a little JNI demo with Autotools using the Clion IDE.
The problem is: I don't know how to tell Autotools to include jni.h.
Also Clion does not resolve the #include <jni.h>.

This is the bare minimun example I'd like you to tell me how to fix [demo](https://github.com/Akrax/jnidemo/tree/main).

Comment: The IDE (CLion) doesn't matter and you have to tell your compiler where is the include directory for `jni.h`. Something like `gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/include`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thank you! I'd like to get the IDE to know about the .h to get hints and checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $JAVA_HOME must be set.

The fixed configure.ac looks like this:

```
AC_INIT([helloworld], [0.1], [maintainer@example.com])
AX_JNI_INCLUDE_DIR
for JNI_INCLUDE_DIR in $JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS
do
    CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$JNI_INCLUDE_DIR"
done
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

CLion will then include the jni.h correctly.